# remove the tr jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the jquery to append rows in a table. But I am finding difficulty to remove the row.
What should I tag in the parent to remove the row?

> e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('tr').remove(); x--;

```js
$(document).ready(
  function (){
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(
      function (e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields)
        { //max input box allowed
          x++; //text box increment
          $(wrapper)
          .append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/></td> <td><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></td></tr>'); //add input box
        }
      }
    );

    $(wrapper).on(
      "click",
      ".remove_field",
      function (e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this)
        .parent('tr')
        .remove();
        x--;
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="input_fields_wrap" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="mytext[]" /></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove TR tag?

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').remove();` ?

Comment: a row(tr) is appending on add more field click. a whole row(tr) should be removed on click of remove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(this).parent().closest('tr').remove();
```

Replace this code in your case

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text        
        e.preventDefault();  $(this).parent().closest('tr').remove(); x--;
    })
```

[Working example for your scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6979/)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
```

Instead of

```
    $(this).parent('tr').remove();
```

Comment: Its now working fine.Its removing my all row that i added.

Answer (score 0):

Stop wrapping `wrapper` and `add_button` in `$()`, you wrap it once during variable declaration and that is *enough*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/></td> <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_field">Remove</a></td></tr>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
     $(this).closest('tr').remove(); x--;
})
});

</script>
<style>


</style>
</head> 

<body>


<table class="input_fields_wrap" border="1">
<tr><td><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/></td><td><a href="#"class="remove_field">Remove</a></td></tr>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
 </table>



</body>
</html>
```